# Php regex to get results of 4 strings between slashes

Tags: php, regex

I'm having troubles with regex. I'm trying to isolate query results that are like :

```
string1/string2/string3/string4

string1/string2/string3/string4/string5
```

I want to find the first case from the two above, the one with the chain ending after "string4".
I've tryied this regex that doesn't actually works :

```
$my_regex = "/^(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)$/";
if (preg_match($my_regex, $category->name)) {
     ...
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: why not `explode()` on `/`, then look at the last item in the array? If it's `string4`, you've got a match. Or even just count how many `/` are in there. if it's 3, you've also got a match.

Comment: "_the first case, where the chain ends after the string4, not including anything else_" - What result do you want from the two examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a regex, a solution could be :

```
$my_regex = "/^([^\/]+\/){3}[^\/]+$/";
if (preg_match($my_regex, $category->name)) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: It works perfect ! What does the + means at the end ?

Comment: It means the previous group can be repeat one or many time. * is 0, one, or many time. And ? is 0 or 1 time. You can use http://www.regexper.com/ to better understand regex

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex, use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode) function

```
$pieces = explode("/", $your_string); //pieces will be an array
foreach($pieces as $piece) {
   [...]
}
```

Comment: In my case, as the "string" strings are totally random, I thought a regex would be easier. Or I'd have to count how much slashes to explode or so.

Comment: @SirBeute: of course no. explode will explode all string snippets between any slash char

Comment: @SirBeute: you can easily obtain the number of items with `count($pieces)`.